# Find the moments $M_x$, $M_y$, and the $x$ and $y$-coordinates of the center of mass of the system

Tags: integration

The following masses mi are located at the given points $P_i: m_1=6, P_1(1,5), m_2=5,P_2(3,−2), m_3=10,P_3(−2,−1)$. Find the moments $M_x$, $M_y$, and the $x$ and $y$-coordinates of the center of mass of the system.

$M_x= ?$

$M_y= ?$

$x$-coordinate of the center of mass: $x= ?$

$y$-coordinate of the center of mass: $y= ?$

Comment: Your attempt on this?

Comment: This doesn't really involve integration. You might want to pick a better tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since formulas for $M_x$ and $M_y$ are
$M_x =\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{3}{m_ky_k}}$ and $M_y =\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{3}{m_ky_k}}$, we have

$M_x=6(5)+5(-2)+10(-1)=30-10-10=10$
$M_y=6(1)+5(3)+10(-2)=6+15-20=1$

We set $M=m_1+m_2+m_3=6+5+10=21$

Then, the coordinates of the center of mass are $x=\dfrac{M_y}{M}=\dfrac{1}{21}$ and $y=\dfrac{M_x}{M}=\dfrac{20}{21}$.